# Search a mysql table colunm stored as an array and then join another table based on result

Tags: mysql, arrays, search, match

I am working on a blog website and stuck at this:

MySQL

1. '`cat_list`' table contains columns: `cat_id`, `cat_name` (14 entries),
2. '`post`' table have several columns where `category` is one of them where I need to store the **category id** in which the blog post was tagged to. the category ids are stored in an `array(19820,83729)`. [because a blog post can be tagged in multiple categories]

I was trying to search '`post`' by one category ID and join '`cat_list`' to retrieve the `cat name`.
Please help me to do this or is there any other alternative database design I should consider?

Comment: is your question solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your post can be tagged with several categories your table model is wrong. You need an associative table between the blog post and the categories. Remove `category id` from `post` table and create a table `post-category` with columns `post-id` and `category-id`. Then also add indexes on theses two columns to speed up search in both directions (by category or by post).

Comment: To elaborate on @regilero answer you need to make sure that post and category has an many to one relationship. In other words your post can only have one category, but each category can have multiple posts. If a post can have multiple categories then you will have a many-to-many relationship. In which case you need to create a bridge table (post_to_category). In this table you store the post_id and category_id. If post 1 has two categories (cat1 & cat3) the entries in the post_to_category table will become 1 | 1 and  1 | 3 (post_id | category_id). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.cat_name FROM post as p 
LEFT JOIN cat_list AS c
ON c.cat_id = p.cat_id
WHERE p.post_id = "3"
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE cat_list(
  cat_id int auto_increment primary key,
  cat_name varchar(30)
  );

CREATE TABLE post (
  post_id int auto_increment primary key,
  cat_id int,
  post varchar(30)
  );

INSERT INTO cat_list (cat_name)
VALUES ("cat1"),("cat2"), ("cat3"),("cat4"),("cat5"),("cat6"),("cat7"),("cat8");

INSERT INTO post (cat_id, post)
VALUES (1,"jnkljlkajlkjaoiuweiuoi"), (1,"wuoieuoiuoidudjhkj"), (2,"eiuuqueiuriewuqyiuu"), (8,"vzbvbxvnbxmnbmn nmncmn");
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7371/5)

Change the ID of the post to select the category.

Comment: @Debraj Debbarma have you tried my answer? Let me know if I can help you.